# How to query for things in a table while excluding others

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey guy I'm new to SQL and I'm stuck trying to figure out how to go about this. I need to produce a list of all the film titles that include either Kevin Bloom or Adam Grant or neither of them. So basically I'm trying to display all the movies that don't feature both of them at the same time. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT f.title as 'Films'
FROM film f
INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
INNER JOIN actor a ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
WHERE (a.first_name != 'Adam' AND a.last_name !='Grant'
   AND a.first_name = 'Kevin' AND a.last_name = 'Bloom') 
   OR (a.first_name != 'Kevin' AND a.last_name !='Bloom'
   AND a.first_name = 'Adam' AND a.last_name = 'Grant')
   OR (a.first_name != 'Kevin' AND a.last_name !='Bloom'
   AND a.first_name != 'Adam' AND a.last_name != 'Grant)
GROUP BY f.title
ORDER BY f.title DESC
```

It seems that I am producing movies but some of them are movies where both actors were present which is what I don't want. I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong. Any help and explanation is greatly appreciated!

Comment: please give a try with : SELECT        film.title
FROM            actor INNER JOIN
                         film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id INNER JOIN
                         film ON film_actor.film_id = film.film_id
WHERE        (actor.first_name NOT IN ('Adam', 'Kevin')) AND (actor.last_name NOT IN ('Grant', 'Bloom'))

Comment: can you please describe structure of all your tables?

Comment: Did you try a version using CONCAT(a.first_name, a.last_name)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation over each film to check whether a film has either both Kevin Bloom and Adam Grant present, or none of them.  To ensure that a check for a person is performed logically correctly, you should enclose the check in parenthesis.

```
SELECT f.title AS 'Films',
    SUM(CASE WHEN ((a.first_name = 'Kevin' AND a.last_name = 'Bloom') OR
                   (a.first_name = 'Adam' AND  a.last_name = 'Grant'))
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nameMatchCount
FROM film f
INNER JOIN film_actor fa
    ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
INNER JOIN actor a
    ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
GROUP BY f.title
HAVING nameMatchCount = 0     -- both are absent
    OR nameMatchCount = 2     -- both are present
ORDER BY f.title DESC
```

Comment: Hey Tim, for some reason I am getting an error when I try to run your query. Also can you explain the HAVING part?

Comment: @tntsgoboom As MySQL is aggregating each group (which is a collection of records belonging to a given film), it will keep a tally every time it sees a record with Kevin Bloom or Adam Grant.  If that tally, for a given film, be 0, then neither appeared, and if it be 2, then both appeared.

Comment: I would have given a Fiddle, but you have several joins, and there is no sample data, so I did not see the point in trying to make one.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your time. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent solution from Tim. But it is not possible to refer to Aliases in the HAVING Statement.

```
WITH CTE_FILM AS
(
   SELECT
       [F_ID]
      ,[F_Name]
   FROM
      (VALUES  
          (1, N'Neither Kevin, nor Adam')
         ,(2, N'Both Kevin and Adam')
         ,(3, N'Only Kevin')
         ,(4, N'Only Adam')
      ) T([F_ID],[F_Name])
),
CTE_FILMACTOR AS
(
   SELECT
       [F_ID]
      ,[A_ID]
   FROM
      (VALUES  
                        (1, 3),(1, 4)
         ,(2, 1),(2, 2),(2, 3)
         ,(3, 1)       ,(3, 3)
                ,(4, 2)       ,(4, 4)
      ) T([F_ID],[A_ID])
),
CTE_ACTOR AS
(
   SELECT
       [A_ID]
      ,[A_FirstName]
      ,[A_LastName]
   FROM
      (VALUES  
          (1, N'Kevin', N'Bloom')
         ,(2, N'Adam' , N'Grant')
         ,(3, N'Will' , N'Smith')
         ,(4, N'Chris', N'Pine')
      ) T([A_ID],[A_FirstName],[A_LastName])
)
SELECT 
    T01.[F_ID]
   ,T01.[F_Name]
   ,SUM(CASE WHEN ((T03.[A_FirstName] = 'Kevin' AND T03.[A_LastName] = 'Bloom') OR
                   (T03.[A_FirstName] = 'Adam' AND  T03.[A_LastName] = 'Grant'))
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS nameMatchCount   
FROM
   CTE_FILM T01
   LEFT JOIN CTE_FILMACTOR T02
   ON
     T01.[F_ID] = T02.[F_ID]
   LEFT JOIN CTE_ACTOR T03
   ON
     T02.[A_ID] = T03.[A_ID]
GROUP BY
    T01.[F_ID]
   ,T01.[F_Name]
HAVING
   SUM(CASE WHEN ((T03.[A_FirstName] = 'Kevin' AND T03.[A_LastName] = 'Bloom') OR
                   (T03.[A_FirstName] = 'Adam' AND  T03.[A_LastName] = 'Grant'))
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
   OR
   SUM(CASE WHEN ((T03.[A_FirstName] = 'Kevin' AND T03.[A_LastName] = 'Bloom') OR
                   (T03.[A_FirstName] = 'Adam' AND  T03.[A_LastName] = 'Grant'))
             THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
```

Comment: Marcus, the OP is using MySQL, at least based on the tag of the question.  In MySQL, it is possible to use an alias in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Oh sorry! The above script is T-SQL